# How to pass parameters in Open CTI Run Apex method from CTI Flow block?

Tags: apex, opencti, cti, softphone, amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

I am trying to call apex class from CTI flow and pass the chat message/content to apex class.

Please refer the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_runapex.htm

below is my class

```
global class GetChatMessageFromAdaptor {

    global static void fetchUserinput(String strUserInputMsg){
        system.debug('===strUserInputMsg========'+strUserInputMsg);
    }
}
```

Here it is mentioned that we have to use like

> name=acme&phone=(212) 555-5555

But the chat message/content is dynamic not like "acme" static value.

> strUserInputMsg=$.actions.uid-11.results.content

or

> strUserInputMsg=$.actions.uid-11.results.value

I am trying to access the value and assigning to strUserInputMsg parameter

CTI Flow Configuration screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, and it take me a day to find a work around solution, with is use the "JoinString" block.
join the "parameter key word" and the "$.actions.uid-11.results...."
the apex block then use the result of the join.

[image]